# Allowing file bookmarks

Tags: filesystem

I work with vim netranger for file management. The version I use doesn't have a bookmark feature for files.
That means to be able to quickly navigate to a  common files by a defined keyboard shortcut.

Do you know of an external plugin that does?

Comment: Have you already considered using upper case marks?

Comment: Didn't occur to me. It is good. Displaying the maps shouldn't be that hard. I can write it using fzf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [vim-bookmark](https://github.com/ipod825/vim-bookmark) which is really basic... but it is fine.

Comment: Remark: It seems not to support Windows.

Comment: I use it on windows

Answer (score 3):

Vim includes this as a [standard feature](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#mark-motions).

You can mark a location in a file with any upper case letter: [`mA`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#m). You can then jump to your bookmark with either a single quote or backtick: [`` `A ``](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%27A).

The marks are saved when you exit Vim.

(Sidenote: Suddenly discovering — after knowing it existed for many years — that this feature could be used for *permanent* bookmarks was a game changer for me. Before that point I'd never once used an uppercase mark. Now I have several that I use to jump to files I access frequently. e.g. I have mark `'T` at the top of a TODO file so I can very quickly capture work items whatever I'm doing.)